# Only last row is inserted when trying to send an array

Tags: php, mysqli

I've a table that contains form input fields where values come from database. Now I wanted to submit the values in a new table in database. But when I press submit button only the last row is inserted! What is the mistake I am making? Please help.

**Data fetching Code:**

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['show'])) {

            $class = $_POST["Class"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Class='$class'  ORDER BY Roll ";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 85%;text-align: center">

         <tr >
           <th>Roll</th>
           <th>Student's Name</th>
           <th>Attendance</th>

</tr>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
          <tr>
      <td><input value="<?php echo $row['Roll']; ?>" name="Roll[]" readonly required=""/></td>
      <td><input value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>" name="Name[]" readonly required=""/></td>
       <td><select name="Status[]">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              </select></td>

       </tr>

   <?php } ?>

 </table>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" style="width: 50%;margin-left: 20%">

</form>

 <?php
} else {
$message = "Sorry! No result!";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            }
  $conn->close();
}
?>
```

**Array inserting Code:**

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {

foreach ($_POST["Roll"] as $rec => $value) {
$Roll = $_POST["Roll"][$rec];

$Name = $_POST["Name"][$rec];
$Status = $_POST["Status"][$rec];
$Date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `attendance`(`id`, `Date`, `Roll`, `Name`, `Status`) VALUES ('','$Date','$Roll','$Name','$Status')";


}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 $message = "Saved !";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to call `$conn->query(...)` within your `foreach` loop, not after it.

Comment: Thanks a lot..man.That solved my issue. :-) But there is a problem that when i submit ..the script i used for showing a alert message also loops !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the relevant line with this:

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `attendance`(`id`, `Date`, `Roll`, `Name`, `Status`) VALUES ('','$Date','$Roll','$Name','$Status');";
```

Then before the foreach loop add:

```
$sql = "";
```

If you are using mysqli, then you'll also need to replace your if statement with this:

```
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

This will combine all of your inserts into one string that can be executed with one query statement, rather than putting query in the foreach and making n number of calls to the database.

Comment: Are you using mysqli?

Comment: Yap. Is that a issue??

Comment: Yes you have to use a different function to execute multiple queries when using mysqli. I updated my answer and that should resolve all those SQL syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

1) As posted earlier in a comment by John Ellmore:

You need to call $conn->query(...) within your foreach loop, not after it. –

2) This problem probably would have been more easily noticed by you if your code were "prettier". Indent three spaces for each loop or other inclusion. and outdent back to normal when you exit the inclusions. Then you'd have (probably) very easily seen your issue. These "best practices" items are often pooh-poohed by "pros" and even by newbies. But a good IDE will help you with this indentation process and likely make life easier every day of coding.